# Using XDocument to read the root element from XML using C# is not showing the root element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I am new to C# programming and trying to update the XML file using C#. Here when I am trying to get the root element using XDocument it is showing the complete script in the file.

Below is my code explanation:

I am having the below function and it is reading the file path from the command line arguments.

```
private XDocument doc;

public void Update(string filepath)
{
   string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

   doc = xDocument.Load(filepath);

   XElement rootelement = doc.Root;

}
```

Into the filepath variable, we are taking the path "E:\BuilderTest\COMMON.wxs"

Then we are loading the file using XDocument.

But when we are trying to get the rootelement from the file, it is not showing the root element. Instead, it is showing the complete data in the file.

But when I am using XmlDocument() instead of XDocument() I am able to see only the root element.

Below is the code using XmlDocument():

```
private XmlDocument doc;

public void Update(string filepath)
{
   string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

   doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load(filepath);

   XmlElement rootelement = doc.DocumentElement;
}
```

Please help me by providing your valuable inputs on this.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by *it is not showing the root element. Instead it is showing the complete data in the file*?  The [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) of an XML document "encloses all the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the other elements."  Thus it makes sense that it is "showing" the document contents -- depending upon how you access it.  So, can you share how you are accessing it and getting more data than you want -- i.e. a [mcve] that shows non-working code?

Comment: Post your xml so we can help you

Comment: I mean -- It is not showing the root element -- From my .wxs file i should get "Wix" as the root element but i am getting the entire code. Here is my .wxs file      <wix xmlns="httpp://......">    <Fragment> <Directory Ref ...> <component .....> <File Id=""...>

Comment: @prakash - that's nowhere near a valid XML. Also, `doc.Root` *does* give you the root element. And also a list of all elements *inside* the root element because linq2xml is convenient like that. So why is that a problem? If you don't need the child elements simply ignore them. What use case do you have, where having convenient access to all child elements poses a problem?

Answer (score 2):

`XDocument` and `XmlDocument` are different class structure to follow as per requirement.

**XDocument will work like below**

```
XDocument doc;
doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
XElement root = doc.Root;
```

Root, Descendants, Elements are the operations provided in `XDocument`. For every node its gives XElement

In your case you should use `doc.Root` to find the element, then use `.Value` to get its value

`XElement` comes with `System.Xml.Linq`. It is derived from `XNode`.
It gives you serialized information of every node one by one.

**On the other hand XMLDocument will work like below**

```
XmlDocument doc;
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filepath);
XmlElement rootelement = doc.DocumentElement;
```

`XmlElement` comes with `System.Xml`. It is derived from `XmlNode` which is again derived from `IEnumerable`.
It gives you information in a Enumerable which you can easily parse.